# Java 3D Texture Deformation

Tags: opengl, java-3d

I have a question about Texture 2D on QuadArray 3D.

When I apply a texture on quad array the result is not what I expect:
[Texture on quadarray I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPtJE.jpg)

Since the quad is plane I expect a more smooth texture deformation:
[Texture I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHuoi.jpg)

Here is the code I use:

```
public class Test3D extends JPanel {
SimpleUniverse simpleU;
static boolean application = false;

public BranchGroup createSceneGraph() {
    BranchGroup objRoot = new BranchGroup();
    Appearance polygon1Appearance = new Appearance();

    GeometryInfo polygon1 = new GeometryInfo(GeometryInfo.QUAD_ARRAY);

    polygon1.setTextureCoordinateParams(1, 2);

    polygon1.setCoordinates(new Point3f[]{new Point3f(0f, 0f, 0f), new Point3f(2f, 0f, 0f), new Point3f(3f, 3f, 0f), new Point3f(-3f, 3f, 0f)});

    polygon1.setTextureCoordinates(0, new TexCoord4f[]{new TexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f)//
            , new TexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f) //
            , new TexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f) //
            , new TexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f)});

   NormalGenerator normalGenerator = new NormalGenerator();
   normalGenerator.generateNormals(polygon1);

   Texture texImage = new TextureLoader("texture.png", this).getTexture();

   polygon1Appearance.setTexture(texImage);
   objRoot.addChild(new Shape3D(polygon1.getGeometryArray(), polygon1Appearance));
   return objRoot;
}

public Test3D() {
    init();
}



public void init() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Canvas3D c = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
    add("Center", c);
    BranchGroup scene = createSceneGraph();
    simpleU = new SimpleUniverse(c);
    TransformGroup tg = simpleU.getViewingPlatform().getViewPlatformTransform();
    Transform3D t3d = new Transform3D();
    t3d.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0f, 0f, 10f));
    tg.setTransform(t3d);
    scene.compile();
    simpleU.addBranchGraph(scene);
}



public static void main(final String[] args) {
    application = true;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.add(new Test3D());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Does anybody have any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, The shape is a plane trapeze , there is not any triangle. By changing positions, i have almost the same result as if Java3d split the trapeze into 2 triangles and put the texture on it...

Comment: *as if Java3d split the trapeze into 2 triangles and put the texture on it* [spoiler: if not by Java, then by your graphics card] you'll have to deal with that fact.

Comment: The issue is explained here: [http://www.xyzw.us/~cass/qcoord/](http://www.xyzw.us/~cass/qcoord/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, the solution in http://www.xyzw.us/~cass/qcoord/ works for trapezoidal geometry, but for non specific quads this solution does not work.

Ex :

```
  polygon1.setCoordinates(new Point3f[]{new Point3f(0f, 0f, 0f), new Point3f(2f, -1f, 0f), new Point3f(3f, 3f, 0f), new Point3f(-4f, 3f, 0f)});
```